# How to remove the header in the Index's pages

Tags: header-footer, indexing

I used `fancy` to customize the header. As usual, there is no header in the Index's pages, but after my customizing, there is a header in them. So how can I remove those header?

Since the index page is quite long so I decide to post my customization only. Here is my customization:

```
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} 
\fancyhead{} 
\fancyhead[RO]{\slshape CÁC BÀI GIẢNG VỀ TOÁN CHO MIRELLA} 
\fancyhead[LE]{\slshape \leftmark}
```

And here is the result:

[image]

Comment: Using `\pagestyle{plain}` before the index starts doesn't work?

Comment: This works. Thanks. I used `\thispagestyle` and it did not work but `\pagestyle` works very well.

Comment: `\thispagestyle` works only for the current page, `\pagestyle` for all subsequent ones.

Answer (score 4):

If you use `imakeidx` as suggested in my answer to your other question, it's easy:

```
\documentclass[11pt,twoside]{report}
\usepackage[paperwidth=16cm,paperheight=24cm,headheight=17pt]{geometry}

\usepackage{imakeidx}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{vietnam}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} 
\fancyhead{} 
\fancyhead[RO]{\slshape CÁC BÀI GIẢNG VỀ TOÁN CHO MIRELLA} 
\fancyhead[LE]{\slshape \leftmark}

\makeindex[title=Tra cứu theo vần]
\indexsetup{othercode={\fancyhead{}}}

\begin{document}
\section*{Chuyển sang tứ giác} \index{hình vuông} 
\index{đối xứng trục}       

\index{đối xứng quay}

 Nhóm đối xứng \index{Nhóm đối xứng, i.e the symmetric group} của một tứ giác. 
\index{how can I do?} Ok let's see. 

% The following code issues 200 \index commands just to fill some pages
\count255=0
\loop\ifnum\count255<200
  \advance\count255 by 1
  \begingroup\edef\x{\endgroup\noexpand\index{\romannumeral\count255 }}\x
\repeat


\newpage 

\printindex
\end{document}
```

The trick is to use `othercode` to unset the headers just in the index.